# UISearchbar (UISearchResultsUpdating) with Segue is still visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a problem with a UISearchBar. When ill search some Text in combination with an UITableView, and ill click on one result Cell, the UISearchBar is still visible in the next View Controller. If ill go back (with Segues) - the UISearchbar is still there (with the Keyword)

So after ill click on one result, ill get (in the next View Controller):

[image]

Ill use it this way:

```
class ...: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var filterSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filterSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        filterSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        filterSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        filterSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
        filterSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = filterSearchController.searchBar
```

Any ideas what could be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dismiss the UISearchController yourself before transitioning to the next view controller with:

```
filterSearchController.active = false
```